# Horizontal scroliing overflowing parent in flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to create 2 column divs in which one of them is scrollable horizontally (no wrap), but it keeps overflowing his parent container. The problem is both divs are using flex to calculate their size.

Is there a way to prevent the overflowing except using a fixed width on one of them?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="small-container">

  </div>
  <div class="large-container">
    <div class="horiz-container">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.small-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.large-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.horiz-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0m6Lj2re/

Comment: Why you dont want a fixed width?

Comment: Because I want both of the columns to be rational to the screen's width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes made are in classes `.large-container`, `.horiz-container` and `.box`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.small-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    background-color: salmon;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.large-container {
    background-color: lightBlue;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.horiz-container {
    /*height: 200px;*/
    background-color: purple;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="small-container">

    </div>
    <div class="large-container">
        <div class="horiz-container">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be scrollable horizontally, so it needs to be flex: nowrap. I added it in the question body to be more precise. Thanks :)

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: @Chelouche, when you get enough ratings to be able to vote, I will be happy to give me a positive rating on this post! Good luck with the project :)

Comment: No problem, I will. Your advice was really helpful. I struggled with it for some time.

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful :) You can mark this answer as accepted answer.